# For lighning:recordEditForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I want to part 2 columns in my record edit form because it has too many fields.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a multi-column layout for your record edit layout, use the Grid utility classes in Lightning Design System. This example creates a two-column layout. [Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation)

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="003XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" objectApiName="Contact">
        <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <!-- Your lightning:inputField components here -->
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <!-- More lightning:inputField components here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: how can i get buttons in the middle

Comment: <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
        <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
            <lightning:button label="Cancel" />
            <lightning:button type="submit" label="Save Record" />
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: okay thanks if i want ask some question then where can i contact you.